# React Native/Expo AV interrupt sound playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Developing a playlist app that has to make an API and retrieve song data in between playing them. The songs load and they play, but if a user was to spam the "next" button it often loads up multiple instances causing them to play on top of each other.

I think the problem is when a new song is selected while another is still loading. Is there a way to create a more interruptible function?

**State**

```
    this.activeAudio = null
    this.state = {
      activeSection: 0,
      volume: 1,
      rate: 1.0
    }
```

**On Mount**

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
      allowsRecordingIOS: false,
      interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
      playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
      shouldDuckAndroid: true,
      interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
      staysActiveInBackground: true,
      playThroughEarpieceAndroid: true
    })
    await this.loadNewSong(true)
  }
```

**On Change Event**

```
changeSong = (index) => {
    const currentIndex = this.state.activeSection
    if (index !== currentIndex) {
      this.setState({ activeSection: index }, () => this.loadNewSong(true))
    }
  }
```

**Song Change**

```
  async loadNewSong(playing) {
    if (this.activeAudio) {
      this.activeAudio.unloadAsync()
      this.activeAudio.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(null)
      null
    }

    const source = { uri: this.props.songList[this.state.activeSection].url }

    const initialStatus = {
      shouldPlay: playing,
      rate: this.state.rate,
      volume: this.state.volume
    }

    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      source,
      initialStatus,
      this.onPlaybackStatusUpdate
    )
    this.activeAudio = sound

  }
```